# Unable to import pyodbc on apple M2

Tags: python, macos, pyodbc

I'm currently trying to import pyodbc in visual studiocode.
It worked for a bit and then stopped working - i'm now getting the error 'dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_SQLAllocHandle''

I saw a few other questions online that had the same issue, and  that people had uninstalled it and then used the following command to reinstall:
pip install --no-binary :all: pyodbc

This fixed my issue for about 5 minutes. It's now throwing the same error above.
Is there anyway to get this working on an apple M2?  I brought this laptop as it was the most recommended one in forums for data engineers, but getting basic functionality has been an absolute nightmare on this thing.

brew install unixodbc
pip install --no-binary :all: pyodbc

import pyodbc

Is there some sort of setting on a mac that could be blocking my access to pyodbc?
I've removed conda from my system as I thought this could be interacting in some way with my python install too.

TIA :)

Comment: This is often caused by having multiple installations of Python.  You probably have the system's python, and a version you installed with HomeBrew.  You need to be very careful about that.  You might do `which -a python3` to see how many you have.  You can use a symlink in `~/bin` to link to the one you always want to use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.